# How do I partition an SD card with "disk utility"?

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, sd-card, disk-utility, card-reader

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I want to make partitions on my SD card. After mounting the SD card I'm trying to make the partitions with the "disk utility". In the disk utility, after clicking on "more actions", the option for edit partitions is not displaying. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about disk utility - I prefer gparted - but some general things: Before you can edit the partitions on a medium, you have to unmount them all (but beware of the difference between "unmount" and "safely remove" - the latter will also send an eject command, making your card inaccessible until you physically remove it from your system). From your screenshot I see that your sdcard does not have a partition table yet (the current file system is written directly to the cards device), so you need to create a new partition table before you can add partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you following steps because a file system across the entire SD Card.

*First*, Backup files.

You must backup your datas from your SD Card to any other volume.

*Second*, Use fdisk command.

Press `Ctrl+Alt+T`.
enter following commands.

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
Command (m for help): o
Command (m for help): w
```

*Third*, Rerun `disk utility`.